# iAd Producer - How to open a URL in safari?

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, iad

I'm just doing some initial research into creating iAds with iAd Producer, but we'd like to link the ad to an external website, rather than an iTunes listing.

Is this possible, if so, how would you go about it? Ideally clicking on the ad would open the link in Safari, but if there is a UIWebView equivalent that would be fine too (The WebGL view control confusingly seems to be for displaying 3d objects).

Many thanks in advance.

Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've realised now I was overcomplicating things somewhat / missed the easy answer.

The iAds produced by iAd Producer are all HTML, with Javascript added to handle page / control events. This should have given me the clue that they themselves are executing in some sort of UIWebView control.

Hence, when I added the following Javascript, on a button click event, the user is warned they are leaving the app (well they were when leaving the iAd Tester app) and then thrown out into Safari to view the website, as I wanted all along. Simple. I guess it's not really what Apple want people to do with iAds (it's not driving them to the appstore), hence it's not that well documented.

```
this.onViewTouchUpInside = function (event) {
document.location = "http://www.google.co.uk";
```

};

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with iAds, what does it look like when specified in HTML?

According to this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html 
it looks like it won't be recognized.

(This is s useful reference in this area: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

But if you load the page in a UIWebView you can intercept the iAds link within shouldStartLoadWithRequest: and launch Safari yourself from there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Martin. However, I don't think iAds are run as native code on the iPhone, they're actually HTML, but with iOS type events firing on them (touch up inside etc), which are handled in Javascript. The fact that they use Javascript and not Objective C, finally lead me to realise that they are actually run inside a UIWebview (I guess), and so I could fire normal url navigating Javascript to open the page i'm after.